# SiteFinity- Included Captcha Form Widget does not contain alt tag

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-feather

SiteFinity noob here.

I've edited the widget via File Manager: Resource Packages>Bootstrap>MVC>Views>Captcha.

the file there is "Write.default.cshtml". I changed the following line-

```
    <img data-sf-role="captcha-image" src='@Url.WidgetContent("assets/dist/img/dummy.jpg")'/>
```

to

```
    <img data-sf-role="captcha-image" alt="captcha Image src='@Url.WidgetContent("assets/dist/img/dummy.jpg")'/>
```

However, although saved, this doesn't show up in the widget code when I put it on my form. I used File Manager, as I dont have a connection via .net editor.

**Am I in the wrong place? Do I need to somehow restart the application?**

Here is complete code:

```
@model Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.Forms.Mvc.Models.Fields.Captcha.CaptchaViewModel

@using Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.Mvc.Helpers;
@using Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Pages;
@using Telerik.Sitefinity.Services;

@Html.Script(ScriptRef.JQuery, "top", false)
<div data-sf-role="field-captcha-container" style="display:none;" class="@Model.CssClass form-group">
<div>
    **<img data-sf-role="captcha-image" src='@Url.WidgetContent("assets/dist/img/dummy.jpg")'/>**
</div>

<a data-sf-role="captcha-refresh-button">@Html.Resource("NewCode")</a>

<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input data-sf-role="violation-messages" type="hidden" value='{"required": "@Model.ValidatorDefinition.RequiredViolationMessage"}' />
        <label for='@Html.UniqueId("Textbox")'>@Html.Resource("TypeCodeAbove") </label>
        <input id='@Html.UniqueId("Textbox")' type="text" data-sf-role="captcha-input" name="@Model.CaptchaAnswerFormKey" required="required" class="form-control input-sm"/>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" data-sf-role="captcha-ca" name="@Model.CaptchaCorrectAnswerFormKey" />
<input type="hidden" data-sf-role="captcha-iv" name="@Model.CaptchaInitializationVectorFormKey" />
<input type="hidden" data-sf-role="captcha-k" name="@Model.CaptchaKeyFormKey" />

<input type="hidden" data-sf-role="captcha-settings" value="@Model.GenerateUrl"
  </div>
  @if (SystemManager.IsDesignMode)
   {
  var scriptUrl = Url.WidgetContent("Mvc/Scripts/Captcha/captcha.js");
  var queryAddition = scriptUrl.Contains("?") ? "&" : "?";
  var fullScriptUrl = scriptUrl + queryAddition + string.Format("_={0}", DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks.ToString());
    <script type="text/javascript" src='@fullScriptUrl'></script>
    }
  else
   {
   @Html.Script(Url.WidgetContent("Mvc/Scripts/Captcha/captcha.js"), "bottom", false)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make sure you are using the Bootstrap package. Go to Design > Page Template and see which resource package your page templates are using. Often times it's not the Bootstrap, but a copy of it.

A restart may help as well.

Comment: What's the best method to do a restart for this? De-Activate then re-activate modules?

Comment: Yes, that's a way to do it if you have no access to the server (IIS)